# Maven 1 project importing to IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans, intellij-idea

I've got few old projects in `maven 1`. I want to import them into any IDE (eclipse, netbeans, intellij idea). I've tried everything and it still haven't worked for me. Each ide tries to find `"pom.xml"` file not `"project.xml"`.

I know I can migrate to `maven 2/3` with `"mvn one:compile"` command. But still for now I want safely try to import them to IDE and build those projects. I don't know almost anything about those project, and converting them to higher maven version can cause some bugs (from what I know about old projects).

Comment: I would think you are out of luck here. Maven 1 is discontinued (see https://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x-eol.html) and unless you manage to get a very old build of your IDE of choice which still supports it, I see no way that this could work.

Comment: Any ideas maybe which version of eclipse can handle maven 1? I've tried versions from 3.1 to 3.4 and still there is a problem with importing "maven-eclipse-plugin-1.12.jar" plugin to IDE. After copying it to "plugin" folder and starting eclipse it doesn't show in installed software section.

Comment: Older versions of Eclipse don't handle Maven at all - you would need to find an older m2eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation and I tried to use the Intellij Idea but it doesn't support Maven 1.x projects. I asked the Idea's support team and they answered, that they don't have any plans to support old Maven versions. The ticket: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166710